# Efficiency of mysql search query with a php script

Tags: mysql, performance

I hope someone knowledeable about mysql and efficiency of queries in mysql (php script), can give me some guidance on what of the following two approaches is more efficient.

Simplifying a lot things, I have two mysql tables.

Table A = 200 words, each word is a tag.
Table B = 8 titles that are being uploaded every 4 hours, so, there is a total of (8 x 6) = 48 titles being uploaded every day, each title has an average of 10 words.

I have a php script that at the end of each day, takes each one of the words in table A, looks if it is found in any of the words in the 48 titles and if it finds it, then it tags that title with the word found. Script works well doing that at the present.

So basically what it is doing is 200 searches in 48 titles and tagging each title appropriately if one of the words in table a is found.

Now, i have done a change in the website, and want to tag those titles, instead of once a day, every 4 hours.  So every time the script tags, it will need be tagging only 8 news (instead of 48) and do the same 200 searches but only in 8 titles instead of doing it in 48 titles.  It will do this operation 6 times a day.

Would it be significantly more efficient to change the script, so instead of doing 200 searches in 8 titles (that have a total of (8 x 10 = 80 words), reverse the way it does it?  That means, change it the other way round so it looks if the 80 words (present in  the 8 titles of table B), are present among the 200 words in table A?

In some time titles will be collected every 2 hours (so there will be only 4 titles), then 1 (so 2 titles), so the number of "titles" to be updated with the script will decrease with time.

Will it be more efficient changing the way the script works? Is the improvement going to be relevant enough?

I am thinking that if going this route is the way to go, the optimal way may be to do it both ways, that is, see first how many titles it is going to tag and how many tags.  If it needs to tag more than X titles, then use script A (actual script), but if it needs to tag less than X, then use new script B.

I have explained this simplifying it and at a small scale. The script operates now in 200 different sites (many more to come) where it does this (each site has a different number of tags and a different number of titles to tag per hour) and can soon do it in many more, so an improvement in how effciently the scripts handles this, can improve a lot the full efficiency of the site.

Does it makes sense to do this change?
Is there a calculation I can do to see when this change may make sense or how to calculate the possible improvement in efficiency I may get

Answer (score 0):

Your numbers seem low enough that any working approach feels fast enought to me. To actually tell whether a change matters, you'll have to benchmark things, as computations in that respect are hard to formulate, as they depend on *a lot* of factors.

That said, I believe that taking the word from the title and searching for it in the table of tags should be faster than the current implementation. My reasoning is not so much based on the number of words, but instead on the use of indices: the list of tags will usually be pretty static, and have an index on the tag word, where you'll be looking for an exact match, right? The title, on the other hand, will change so often that creating an index for it might actually decrease performance. And as you'll be looking for a substring match, a normal (i.e. not full text) index won't be of any use.

So I'd say make sure that the list of tags has a proper index. When new titles arrive, split them into words in PHP, then insert these words into a temporary MySQL table, together with the indices. Then you can issue a single update query to add all of the tags, and then drop the temporary table. The update would looks something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO post_tags (post_id, tag_id)
SELECT temp_words.post_id, tags.id
FROM temp_words INNER JOIN tags ON temp_words.word = tags.name
```

This assumes that you have a single table `post_tags` where each row denotes one tag on one post, the way a proper database normalization would require it to be. `temp_tags` is the table holding the words of the newly processed titles.